# Grunt aborted due to warnings

Tags: javascript, cmd, npm, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I have already installed "npm" on my local machine. In my Gruntfile.js directory, i'm installing grunt in this way:

> 1. npm install grunt
> 2. npm install -g grunt-cli
> 3. grunt watch

The tasker is running, but i got these warnings:
[image]

Here's my gruntfile.js file

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        sass: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    style: 'compact',
                    cacheLocation: 'assets/sass/.cache-location',
                },
                files: [{
                    'assets/css/dx-epb-admin.css': 'assets/css/scss/dx-epb-admin.scss',
                    'assets/css/dx-epb-public.css': 'assets/css/scss/dx-epb-public.scss',
                    'assets/css/dx-epb-grid.css': 'assets/css/scss/dx-epb-grid.scss',
                }],
            },
        },

        autoprefixer:{
            dist: {
                files: {
                    'assets/css/dx-epb-admin.css': 'assets/css/dx-epb-admin.css',
                    'assets/css/dx-epb-admin-new.css': 'assets/css/dx-epb-admin-new.css',
                    'assets/css/dx-epb-public.css': 'assets/css/dx-epb-public.css',
                    'assets/css/dx-epb-grid.css': 'assets/css/dx-epb-grid.css',
                },
            },
        },

        watch: {
            scripts: {
                files: ['assets/js/src/*.js'],
                tasks: ['jshint', 'uglify'],
            },
            css: {
                files: [ 'assets/css/**/*.scss', 'assets/css/*.css' ],
                tasks: ['sass', 'autoprefixer', 'cssmin'],
            },
        },

        cssmin: {
            options: {
                shorthandCompacting: false,
                roundingPrecision: -1
            },
            target: {
                files: {
                    'assets/css/dx-epb-admin.min.css': ['assets/css/dx-epb-admin.css'],
                    'assets/css/dx-epb-admin-new.min.css': ['assets/css/dx-epb-admin-new.css'],
                    'assets/css/dx-epb-public.min.css': ['assets/css/dx-epb-public.css'],
                    'assets/css/dx-epb-grid.min.css': ['assets/css/dx-epb-grid.css'],
                }
            }
        },

        uglify: {
            target: {
                files: {                    
                    'assets/js/dx-epb-admin.min.js':
                    [
                        'assets/js/src/dx-epb-admin.js',
                    ],
                    'assets/js/dx-epb-admin-new.min.js':
                    [
                        'assets/js/src/dx-epb-admin-new.js',
                    ],
                    'assets/js/dx-epb-admin-save.min.js':
                    [
                        'assets/js/src/dx-epb-admin-save.js',
                    ],
                    'assets/js/dx-epb-control.min.js':
                    [
                        'assets/js/src/dx-epb-control.js',
                    ],
                    'assets/js/dx-epb-media-upload.min.js':
                    [
                        'assets/js/src/dx-epb-media-upload.js',
                    ],
                    'assets/js/dx-epb-public.min.js':
                    [
                        'assets/js/src/dx-epb-public.js',
                    ],
                    'assets/js/dx-epb-tinymce-button.min.js':
                    [
                        'assets/js/src/dx-epb-tinymce-button.js',
                    ]
                }
            }
        },

        jshint: {
            all: ['Gruntfile.js', 'assets/js/scripts.js'],
        },
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-autoprefixer');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);
    grunt.registerTask('css', ['sass', 'autoprefixer']);
    grunt.registerTask('minify', ['cssmin']);
    grunt.registerTask('minifyjs', ['uglify']);
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install all the missing grunt tasks listed. If you have a package.json file that lists the needed dependencies all you need to do is run `npm install` in the same directory.

Otherwise install each one manually from the command line like:

```
    npm install grunt-sass
    npm install grunt-contrib-watch
    npm install grunt-contrib-jshint
    npm install grunt-contrib-cssmin
    npm install grunt-autoprefixer
    npm install grunt-contrib-uglify
```

Comment: or one liner: 
`npm install grunt-sass grunt-contrib-watch grunt-contrib-jshint grunt-contrib-cssmin grunt-autoprefixer grunt-contrib-uglify`